# Glusterfs client installation on ECS optimized Amazon Linux image

Tags: yum, glusterfs, amazon-linux

I am trying to use ECS optimized image (Amazon linux) and trying to install Glusterfs client on it.

Followed few documents like [this](https://blog.programster.org/setting-up-a-glusterfs-client) internet but all are giving issue with repository. Unable to find the correct repo.

after tring yum install getting no package found error.

Please provide me some guidance to achieve this.